# Is there a way to intercept Network calls from in HeadlessChrome

Tags: google-chrome, docker, headless-browser

I am running headless chrome in a docker container. I am making some http requests with payload. Is there a way to read the payload??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome-remote-interface](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) to talk to chrome in your docker container. But just don't forget to open your port by using this flag
--remote-debugging-port=9222

Here is also a great example how to intercept each call with pattern. [intercept & block calls](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Intercept-and-block-requests-by-URL)